# Post parameters are becoming null (at random)

Tags: web-applications, struts2

My web application is developed with Struts2 and it was working fine till recently. All of a sudden one of the modules has started malfunctioning.

The malfunctioning module is 'Update Student details' page. This page has a lot of fields like 'schoolName', 'degreeName', etc .

```
School 1: <input name="schoolName">

School 2: <input name="schoolName">

..... 
School n: <input name="schoolName">
```

As mentioned earlier, the page was working perfectly fine till recently. Now, one/many of the values of 'schoolName', 'degreeName', etc are being received as "" (EMPTY STRING) on the server-side.

For debugging, I used firebug and remote-debugging in eclipse. I find that the post-parameters are correct on the client-side. For instance, during one of the submissions the post-parameters were as below (i noted them from firebug).

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------2921238217421 
Content-Length: 48893 

<OTHER_PARAMETERS> <!--Truncated for clarity --> 

-----------------------------2921238217421 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="schoolName" 

ABC Institute 
-----------------------------2921238217421 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="schoolName" 

Test School 
-----------------------------2921238217421 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="schoolName" 

XYZ 
-----------------------------2921238217421 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="schoolName" 

Texas Institute 
-----------------------------2921238217421 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="schoolName" 

XXXX School 

-----------------------------2921238217421--
```

But on the server-side, the request params were as below:

```
schoolName=[ABC Institute, Test School, XYZ, , XXXX School],
```

"Texas Institute" was received as "" (EMPTY STRING) in this particular case. This is not happening consistently. The parameters that become NULL (or EMPTY STRING) seem random to me - during one instance, parameter schoolName[3] became null as illustrated above, parameter schoolName[2] became null during yet another submission, etc. At times, none of the parameters are nullified.

The following is the list of the interceptors in the action definition.

```
List of interceptors: 
----------------------
FileUploadInterceptor
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor
ServletConfigInterceptor
org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor  StaticParametersInterceptor
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor
ParametersInterceptor
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor
MyCustomInterceptor
com.xxxx.yyyy.interceptors.GetLoggedOnUserInterceptor
```

This issue appears rather weird to me and I have not been able to zero-in on the exact cause of the issue. Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Thanks, 
Raghuram

Comment: I suggest you first eliminate network transmission problems by capturing the traffic at the server using Wireshark to make sure you are receiving all the data at the adapter.  If the data looks OK there, then you will probably have to load the Struts2 source and debug into the interceptors to see what's happening.  

A question: Is the extra blank line after `XXXX School` really there?

Comment: >>> A question: Is the extra blank line after XXXX School really there?

 Sorry, NO. There is no extra blank line.

Answer (score 1):

An update.

My form sends a multipart request (needed since file upload is enabled on the form). I decided to log the post-data that comes to the server. I modified RequestDumperFilter.java to log the multipart post data. After i added this filter, the parameter loss issue seems to have ceased (0 loss out of 150 submissions of form). I removed the filter and was able to reproduce the issue again.

Thanks,
Raghuram

```
/*
* Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
* contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
* this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
* The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
* (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
* the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
*
*     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
*
* Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
* distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
* WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
* See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
* limitations under the License.
*/


package filters;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletInputStream;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.xml.ws.RequestWrapper;

import com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.BufferedServletInputStream;



/**
 * Example filter that dumps interesting state information about a request
 * to the associated servlet context log file, before allowing the servlet
 * to process the request in the usual way.  This can be installed as needed
 * to assist in debugging problems.
 *
 * @author Craig McClanahan
 * @version $Revision: 500674 $ $Date: 2007-01-28 00:15:00 +0100 (dim., 28 janv. 2007) $
 */

public final class RequestDumperFilter implements Filter {


    // ----------------------------------------------------- Instance Variables


    /**
     * The filter configuration object we are associated with.  If this value
     * is null, this filter instance is not currently configured.
     */
    private FilterConfig filterConfig = null;

    // --------------------------------------------------------- Public Methods


    /**
     * Take this filter out of service.
     */
    public void destroy() {

        this.filterConfig = null;

    }


    /**
     * Time the processing that is performed by all subsequent filters in the
     * current filter stack, including the ultimately invoked servlet.
     *
     * @param request The servlet request we are processing
     * @param result The servlet response we are creating
     * @param chain The filter chain we are processing
     *
     * @exception IOException if an input/output error occurs
     * @exception ServletException if a servlet error occurs
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (filterConfig == null)
        return;

    // Render the generic servlet request properties
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sw);
    writer.println("Request Received at " +
               (new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    writer.println(" characterEncoding=" + request.getCharacterEncoding());
    writer.println("     contentLength=" + request.getContentLength());
    writer.println("       contentType=" + request.getContentType());
    writer.println("            locale=" + request.getLocale());
    writer.print("           locales=");
    Enumeration locales = request.getLocales();
    boolean first = true;
    while (locales.hasMoreElements()) {
        Locale locale = (Locale) locales.nextElement();
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            writer.print(", ");
        writer.print(locale.toString());
    }
    writer.println();
    Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
    while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = (String) names.nextElement();
        writer.print("         parameter=" + name + "=");
        String values[] = request.getParameterValues(name);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (i > 0)
            writer.print(", ");
        writer.print(values[i]);
        }
        writer.println();
    }
    writer.println("          protocol=" + request.getProtocol());
    writer.println("        remoteAddr=" + request.getRemoteAddr());
    writer.println("        remoteHost=" + request.getRemoteHost());
    writer.println("            scheme=" + request.getScheme());
    writer.println("        serverName=" + request.getServerName());
    writer.println("        serverPort=" + request.getServerPort());
    writer.println("          isSecure=" + request.isSecure());

    // Render the HTTP servlet request properties
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        writer.println("---------------------------------------------");
        HttpServletRequest hrequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        writer.println("       contextPath=" + hrequest.getContextPath());
        Cookie cookies[] = hrequest.getCookies();
            if (cookies == null)
                cookies = new Cookie[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            writer.println("            cookie=" + cookies[i].getName() +
                   "=" + cookies[i].getValue());
        }
        names = hrequest.getHeaderNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = (String) names.nextElement();
        String value = hrequest.getHeader(name);
            writer.println("            header=" + name + "=" + value);
        }
        writer.println("            method=" + hrequest.getMethod());
        writer.println("          pathInfo=" + hrequest.getPathInfo());
        writer.println("       queryString=" + hrequest.getQueryString());
        writer.println("        remoteUser=" + hrequest.getRemoteUser());
        writer.println("requestedSessionId=" +
               hrequest.getRequestedSessionId());
        writer.println("        requestURI=" + hrequest.getRequestURI());
        writer.println("       servletPath=" + hrequest.getServletPath());


        /*
        The following section is added by me to print the post data of a multipart request.
        */
        writer.println("=============================================");
        writer.println("POST-DATA:");
        writer.println("----------");
        String line;
        BufferedRequestWrapper bufferedRequest= new BufferedRequestWrapper(hrequest);
        //Here obtain InputStream to process POST data!
        InputStream is = bufferedRequest.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
              writer.println(line);
        }
        writer.println("=============================================");
        // Log the resulting string
        writer.flush();
        filterConfig.getServletContext().log(sw.getBuffer().toString());
        // Pass control on to the next filter
        chain.doFilter(bufferedRequest, response);

    }
    else
    {
        writer.println("=============================================");

        // Log the resulting string
        writer.flush();
        filterConfig.getServletContext().log(sw.getBuffer().toString());

        // Pass control on to the next filter
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    }


    /**
     * Place this filter into service.
     *
     * @param filterConfig The filter configuration object
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;

    }


    /**
     * Return a String representation of this object.
     */
    public String toString() {

    if (filterConfig == null)
        return ("RequestDumperFilter()");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("RequestDumperFilter(");
    sb.append(filterConfig);
    sb.append(")");
    return (sb.toString());

    }

    public class BufferedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        ByteArrayInputStream bais;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
        BufferedServletInputStream bsis;
        byte [] buffer; 

        public BufferedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest req) throws IOException {
        super(req);
        // Read InputStream and store its content in a buffer.
        InputStream is = req.getInputStream();
        baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int letti;
        while ((letti=is.read(buf))>0) baos.write(buf,0,letti);
        buffer = baos.toByteArray();
        }

        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
        try {
        // Generate a new InputStream by stored buffer
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        // Istantiate a subclass of ServletInputStream
        // (Only ServletInputStream or subclasses of it are accepted by the servlet engine!)
        bsis = new BufferedServletInputStream(bais); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
        return bsis;
        }
        }

        }

    /*
    Subclass of ServletInputStream needed by the servlet engine.
    All inputStream methods are wrapped and are delegated to 
    the ByteArrayInputStream (obtained as constructor parameter)!
    */
    public class BufferedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {

    ByteArrayInputStream bais;

    public BufferedServletInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {
    this.bais = bais;
    }

    public int available() {
    return bais.available();
    }

    public int read() {
    return bais.read();
    }

    public int read(byte[] buf,int off,int len) {
    return bais.read(buf,off,len);
    }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this tomcat bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37794

When an HTTP/1.1 client POST with transfer-encoding: chunked to a servlet, 
the getParameter() family and getQueryString() methods fail to retrieve the 
correct result by returning nothing. In contrast, reading until end-of-file 
on the servlets input stream produces correct result.

The fix is in 6.0.21.